# resize items window automatically python interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, tkinter

before asking, I would like to thank all Stackoverflow members
I'm in developing GUI python as you can see  in the photo bellow
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbop6.png)

and that's working as well, the problem appears when I maximize the window as we can see in the photo below again

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6BMp.png)

I want to make from window items resize automatically

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk



path = "C:\\Users\\Elkassah\\Desktop\\Python\\Test sqlite.db"
conn = sqlite3.connect(path)
def insertbd():
    
    part = int(Echantillons.get())
    sex=V0.get()
    age=int(age.get())
    sco=int(Puissance.get())
    
    fonct=cb.get()
    rev=int(Revenu.get())
    red=data2.get()
    rep = (part,sex,age,sco,fonct,rev,red)
    print(rep)
    sql = """insert into enquete (Echantillons, Sexe, Age, Puissance,Fonction, Revenue, Queston1 ) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"""
    with conn as c :
        c.execute(sql,rep)
 
window=Tk()


#backgroud image
canvas = Canvas(window, width = 1500, height = 800)  
canvas.pack()  
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("qlt.png"))  
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=img) 
#logo image
canva = Canvas(window, width = 500, height = 500)  
canva.pack()  
imge = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("download.png"))  
canva.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=imge) 


lbEchantillons=Label(window,text="Echantillons des TV :")
lbEchantillons.place(x=60,y=100)
Echantillons = Entry(window)
Echantillons.place(x=200,y=100)

color=Label(window,text='Couleur d affichage')
color.place(x=60,y=150)

V0 = IntVar()
V0.set(1)

color1=Radiobutton(window, text="Blanc/Noir",variable=V0,value=1)
color1.place(x=200,y=150)

color2=Radiobutton(window,text="Encouleur",variable=V0,value=2)
color2.place(x=300,y=150)



lbPuissance=Label(window,text='Puissance electrique\n en miliWatt',)
lbPuissance.place(x=60,y=200)
Puissance = Entry(window)
Puissance.place(x=200,y=200)

lbTaille=Label(window,text='  Taille de l écran     \n en pouce ',fg='blue' ,bd=0)
lbTaille.place(x=60,y=250)
Taille = Entry(window)
Taille.place(x=200,y=250)

Satisfaction=Label(window,text='Satisfaction du cliente')
Satisfaction.place(x=60,y=350)

V1 = IntVar()
V1.set(1)

Satisfaction1=Radiobutton(window, text="Oui ",variable=V1,value=1)
Satisfaction1.place(x=200,y=350)

Satisfaction2=Radiobutton(window,text="Non ",variable=V1,value=2)
Satisfaction2.place(x=280,y=350)




ok =Button(window,text= "       Validé      ", command=insertbd )
ok.place(x=200,y=400)
window.title("TV report ")
window.geometry("450x470+10+10")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: please provide some code specifically [mre] and what have You tried?

Comment: I suggest reading up on the `pack` and `grid` methods for adding widgets to a window. They make it much easier to create a responsive GUI than does `place`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    width = window.winfo_width()
    height = window.winfo_height()
    img_pil = Image.open(qlt.png)
    rsd_bg_img = img_pil.resize((width,height))
    rsd_bg = canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor = NW,image = rsd_bg_img)

    def on_resize():
        width = window.winfo_width()
        height = window.winfo_height()
        rsd_bg_img = img_pil.resize((width,height))
        canvas.itemconfig(rsd_bg,image = rsd_bg_img)
        #for other widgets, widget_current_width = widget_default_width * (window_current_width/window_default_width),replicated for height.

    window.bind("<Configure>", on_resize)
```

Comment: Callback for `bind()` requires an argument, the event object.